# How to detect if a parameter is not used / not essential for a particular use case?

Tags: python

I have some working code (library) that, in some situations, I only need a small subset of its functional.

Thinking of a simpler case, the code (library) is a class that takes a few parameters when initializing.
For my limited use case, many of those parameters are not vital as they are not directly used in the internal calculation (some parameters are only used when I call particular methods of the object), while it is very hard to prepare those parameters properly.

So, I am wondering, if there is any easy way to know what parameters are essential without fully analyzing the library code (which is too complicated). For example, I may pass fake parameters to the api, And it would raise an exception only if they are actually used.

For example, I can pass in `some_parameter = None` for `some_parameter` that I guess won't be used. So whenever the library tries to access `some_parameter.some_field` an exception would be raised thus I can further look into the issue and replace it by the actually parameter. However, it would change the behavior of the library if the code itself accepts `None` as a parameter.

Are there any established approach to this problem? I don't mind false positive as I can always look into the problem and manually check if the usage of the fake parameters by the library is trivial.

For those suggestions on reading documentation and code, I don't have documentations! And the code is legacy code left by previous developers.

#### Update

@sapi:

Yes I would like to use the proxy pattern / object: I will further investigate on such topic.

"A virtual proxy is a placeholder for "expensive to create" objects. The real object is only created when a client first requests/accesses the object."

Comment: Yes, reading the documentation and code.

Comment: Is there no API documentation? Nothing that tells you what each argument is for? You could make a custom class that throws an error for any attempted interaction, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Did you write this library yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're looking to achieve, you may be able to pass in a proxy object which throws an exception when accessed.

For example:

```
class ObjectUsedException(Exception):
    pass


class ErrorOnUseProxy(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        raise ObjectUsedException('Tried to access %s'%name)
```

Of course, that approach will fail in two pretty common situations:

- if the library itself checks if the attribute exists (eg, to provide some default value)
- if it's treated as a primitive (float, string etc), though you could modify this approach to take that into account

Comment: Thank you for bring term 'proxy object' to me. I can confirm it is what I would like to achieve: "A virtual proxy is a placeholder for "expensive to create" objects. The real object is only created when a client first requests/accesses the object."

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming all classes in question are new-style. This is always the case if you are using Python 3; in Python 2, they must extend from `object`. You can check a class with `isinstance(MyClass, type)`. For the remainder of my answer, I will assume Python 3, since it was not specified. If you are using Python 2, make sure to extend from `object` where no other base class is specified.

If those conditions hold, [you can write a descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) that raises an exception whenever it is accessed:

```
class ParameterUsed(Exception):
    pass

class UsageDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(UsageDescriptor, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        raise ParameterUsed(self.name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # Ignore sets if the value is None.
        if value is not None:
            raise ParameterUsed(self.name)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        # Ignore deletes.
        pass
```

I will assume we are using this class as an example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def use_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def use_b(self):
        print(self.b)
```

If we want to see if `a` is used anywhere, extend the class and put an instance of our descriptor on the class:

```
class ExtExample(Example):
    a = UsageDescriptor('a')
```

Now if we were to try to use the class, we can see which methods use `a`:

```
>>> example = ExtExample(None, None)
>>> example.use_a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ParameterUsed: a
>>> example.use_b()
None
```

Here, we can see that `use_a` tried to use `a` (raising an exception because it did), but `use_b` did not (it completed successfully).

---

This approach works more generally than [sapi’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24346768) does: in particular, sapi’s approach will only detect an attribute being accessed on the object. But there are plenty of things you can do that *do not* access attributes on that object. This approach, rather than detecting attributes being accessed on that object, detects the object itself being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the simplest and least intrusive way is to turn the parameters into properties:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def a(self):
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Accesing parameter a'
        return 1

 bar = Foo()
 print bar.a == 1
```

Will print True in stdout, and `Accesing parameter a` to stderr. You would have to tweak it to allow the class to change it.